# Switched from the Ethereum Wallet's test network to main network and need to remove the previous data

Tags: contract-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp, storage, mac-osx, installation

I was on the Ethereum Wallet's test network and finally worked out all the code, but now that I have switched over to the main network I've had to download a lot of the preexisting blocks and has my Mac's storage nearly full. Is there a way I can clear out the previous data from the test network to free up space? Also, I thought about uninstalling and then installing it again, but I've already sent some ether to the "my account" in the wallet, would I lose that account or can I have it recovered?
Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: As a side note - in terms of development and testing you don't have to run a local node. By using MyEtherWallet (MEW) and MetaMask for example in the browser you can deploy contracts to a specific test network (and the main network) directly.  MetaMask also has a button to press to get test ether from a faucet on the test network.

Answer (score 1):

The chain data are stored by default here: `~/Library/Ethereum`

You can delete the corresponding folder, the one matching the testnet.

Concerning your ether, it is on blockchain. You just have to synchronize again and will see your ether.
(Reading your last answer, you should learn about how blockchain works. Everything is stored on the chain, so everyone on the network has the same information. You delete the information on your side? Does not matter, just synchronize (download from other nodes) and you will see your ether again!)